# Python LoopingCall freezes

Tags: python, twisted

Im trying to create a game server for learning purposes and I've ran into a problem where my updating function that runs every (0.05) seconds, isn't calling any functions that pass variables.

```
def update(self):
    print("Match update: %s" % (str(self)))
    if (self.pendingShutdown):
        cancelShutdown = True
        for player in self.players:
            if player.protocol == None:
                cancelShutdown  = False
        if (time() > self.shutdownTime):
            print("Time elapsed, shutting down match")
            #self.quit()
    else:
        self.sendlocations()
def sendlocations(self):
    print("ran new send locations")
    for player in self.players:
        print(player.posX)
        for r in range(0, len(self.players)):
            matchPlayer = self.players[r]
            #equation for distance between players
            x = (player.posX - matchPlayer.posX)**2
            y = (player.posY - matchPlayer.posY)**2
            distance = math.sqrt(x+y)
            #ending equation
            if (distance <= 1000):
                if (matchPlayer.protocol):
                    #finding the player index(SENDING PLAYER)
                    index = 0
                    for i in matchPlayer.match.players:
                        if(i.playerId == player.playerId):
                            matchPlayer.protocol.sendPlayerMoved(index, player.posX, player.posY, player.posZ)
                        index = index + 1
                        print("Player moved %s " % (index))
def sendPlayerMoved(self, playerIndex, posX, posY, posZ):
    message = MessageWriter()
    message.writeByte(MESSAGE_PLAYER_MOVED)
    message.writeInt(playerIndex)
    message.writeInt(posX)
    message.writeInt(posY)
    message.writeInt(posZ)
    #self.log("Sent PLAYER_MOVED %d %d" % (playerIndex, posX))
    self.sendMessage(message)
```

I'm able to called "self.sendlocations()" and when I do not have the lines passed if(distance<=)
the function properly prints out the line "ran new send locations" but with this line added it does not anymore. After adding the lines the "update" function also freezes up. Im clueless as to why this is happening.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you. Your example is not complete (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://www.sscce.org/) and we cannot infer what `sendPlayerMoved` does. For sure having three nested loops does not help the responsiveness of the server.

Comment: Yes I noticed that right now as I was trying to figure the issue, im going to try and reduce the loops. Also edited the question and added the sendplayermoved.